# Como Jogar os dados de uma Jlist em uma outra Jlist que está em outro Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlist

Tentei de Várias Formas, mas não consegui achar uma solução.
   Quando clico no Botão salvar. Quero que ele jogue os dados dessa Jlist para a outra Jlist que está no Outro Jframe. "Não consegui ativar o bloco de código, me desculpem".

```
//Método para Adicionar os itens na Jlist

private void btAdicionarGastoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        listGasto.setModel(item);
        item.addElement(txtNomeGasto.getText() + ": " + txtValorGasto.getText() + " " + "Data: " +txtData.getText());
        txtNomeGasto.setText("");
        txtValorGasto.setText("R$ ");


    } 
    private void 
    btSalvarGastoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
            int k=0;
            k = listGasto.getFirstVisibleIndex();
            listGasto.setModel(item);
            receita.setItems((ArrayList<String>) item.getElementAt(k));
            this.hide();
        }                                             

           //Codigo no outro Jframe
            private void formInternalFrameOpened(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {                                         
            frm = new frmGastos();
            gastos = new DefaultListModel();

            listDadosGasto.setModel(gastos);
            gastos.addElement(frm.receita.getItems());
            listDadosGasto.repaint();
        }
```

podem me ajudar?

aqui está um link do Google drive de um programa Exemplo: drive.google.com/open?id=0B3LW2w_eQoq4V3BhV0hiQ1o1dnM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a intenção é copiar exatamente todos os itens de um *Jlist* de uma janela para um *JList* de outra, basta passar o `ListModel` do primeiro para o segundo, como parametro da janela. Como seu código não é reproduzível, veja esse exemplo de como passar valores entre janelas:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JListTest extends JFrame {

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        String[] selections = { "green", "red", "orange", "dark blue" };
        JList<String> list = new JList(selections);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(list),BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Salvar");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //inicio a segunda janela e passo o
                // model como parametro para a segunda
                SecondList frame = new SecondList();
                frame.createAndShowGUI(list.getModel());

            }
        });
        add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JListTest().createAndShowGUI();

            }
        });
    }
}

class SecondList extends JFrame{

    public void createAndShowGUI(ListModel model) {

        //recebo o model e ja instancio a jlist com ele 
        JList<String> list = new JList(model);
        list.setModel(model);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(list));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JListTest().createAndShowGUI();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O código deu certo, agora estou tentando implementar no meu programa

Comment: @MateusSilveira testa ai, qualquer coisa avisa aqui.

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Não estou conseguindo implementar. Vou fazer um exemplo e mandar o link do Google Drive pra vcs verem melhor.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3LW2w_eQoq4V3BhV0hiQ1o1dnM

Comment: @MateusSilveira https://ufile.io/abf14 testa ai, mas já adianto que não é uma boa solução, você está misturando lógica de negócio com tela, quase não consegui achar as listas. O editor deveria ser usado apenas pra fazer a janela, sem lógica nenhuma, e depois você adicionar manualmente, não via arrastar e soltar, assim, evita esse engessamento de código que torna até dificil pra você mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou, e obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando dois frames, um com uma lista e um botão que vou chamar de referência.
Primeiramente crio a lista com os itens:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

jListReferencia.setModel(model);
model.addElement("Item 1");
model.addElement("Item 2");
model.addElement("Item 3");
```

Depois crio e instancio o segundo `JFrame` para uma variável privada:

```
private JFrameDestino jFrameDestino;

...

jFrameDestino = new JFrameDestino();
jFrameDestino.setVisible(true);
```

Logo após crio o método público no `JFrameDestino`:

```
public void copiarItensSelecionados(JList jListReferencia) {
  DefaultListModel list = (DefaultListModel) jListDestino.getModel();

  for (Object sel : jListReferencia.getSelectedValuesList()) {
    if (list.indexOf(sel) == -1) {
      list.addElement(sel);
    }
  }
}
```

E no click do botão localizado no `JFrameReferencia` faço a seguinte chamada:

```
private void jButtonCopiarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  jFrameDestino.copiarItensSelecionados(jListReferencia);
}
```